# Can HMAC confirm data existence?

Tags: hash, hmac

I have two hosts, A and B. Host A gives host B a **large** piece of data and deletes it. Host A then needs to periodically confirm host B is holding the piece of data.

Before deleting the data Host A precomputes multiple HMACs with a CSPRNG generated random number (a salt). When Host A needs B to confirm the data still exists, it sends a salt to B, B then computes the HMAC returns it to A.

Is this cryptographically sound?

When computing HMAC(number, data) can you use an intermediate values instead of the actual data? Keccak is used if this affects the answer.

EDIT: [Cross Referencing question on security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158298/can-hmac-confirm-message-existence)

Comment: That sounds pretty solid. FYI, you're essentially describing a *proof of retrievability*, which has been studied quite widely in cryptography literature. [Here](http://www.arijuels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/BJO09b.pdf) is a nice survey.

Comment: In your last paragraph, do you mean HMAC(number, Keccak(data))?  Don't think that'll work...

Comment: @PaulUszak Using Keccak as the cryptograpically secure hash function required for HMAC, instead of SHA-2 which is more vulnerable to length extension attacks.

Comment: @pg1989 That's very useful, I needed some references for my dissertation. Thanks!

Comment: I conjecture that A) yes, what is proposed is secure, including with HMAC-SHA-3 instead of HMAC-SHA-2. B) It does not follow directly from the fact that HMAC (much less, a secure MAC) is used; to prove the security of the proposed construction, we have to "open" the HMAC box, and the SHA box, down the the very compression/sponge function used.

Comment: Is 'salt' the correct terminology here? It seems more like a key to me.

Comment: With Keccak you do not need to use HMAC, you can use KMAC instead, which is much more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attack in this context would be being able to compute valid responses to salt challenges while in possession of information lesser than the piece of data (message).

Lets assume the salt is either the same size as that of the hash function's block or is padded to that size. In essence, the first iteration of the hash function is solely computed with the salt.

Each time you challenge with a salt you are challenging with new state values of the hash function. Basically a new hash function (different default values).

To be able to attack this you would need to break the one-way property of the hash function. You would need to create associativity rules for the hash function - compute iterations of the hash function on the message in such a way that the result can be applied to an arbitrary initial state.

Comment: The reasoning made in this answer requires improvement. In particular, it would be false to state that if H is a secure hash (e.g. in the ROM, preimage resistant..), then being able to compute H(salt || data) or even H((salt xor opad) ||H((salt xor ipad) || data) proves knowledge of data. We need to consider the inner structure of the hash!

Comment: It is possible to make a secure hash such that its data can be compressed. For example, modify SHA-256 into SHA'-256 by changing its compression function F(_state_, _block_) to F'(_state_, _block_) = F(_state_, (F(C,_block_) ||C) ) where C is a 256-bit public constant. Now you can compute HMAC-SHA'-256(_salt_, _data_) without storing the full _data_, only about half of that, by keeping F(C,_block_) rather than _block_ for each block of _data_.